# How to vertically center detail text in a table cell of UITableViewCellStyleValue2 style?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

When I do

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
```

on a cell of **UITableViewCellStyleValue2** style, the line of detail text is top-aligned, i.e. roughly at the same vertical position as the first line of (main) text is. However, I want it to be in the vertical center of the cell. Setting `cell.detailTextLabel.baselineAdjustment` to various values did not help. Can anyone help?

Comment: UITableViewCellStyleValue2 aren't they vertically center aligned?

Comment: I think you might need custom cell for that.

Comment: @Neo Not in the case I have mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the **custom cell** with these two label and set **detailtextLabel**(custom) frame as your want.

Comment: Well, according [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html), it seems you are right, unfortunately -- there is no easier way. Custom `UILabel` in a cell works... Thanks.